# Highchards - data loading from dbase

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I'm looking for a help with loading data from dbase into Higtcharts.
The Highcharts data loading entrance looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
        // Create the chart 
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
            },

            xAxis: {
                maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000 // fourteen days
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: usdeur
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and usdeur is loading as in scheme (example from external csv file):

```
var usdeur = [
[Date.UTC(2011,1,3),0.7488],
[Date.UTC(2011,2,6),0.6983],
[Date.UTC(2011,3,8),0.6961],
[Date.UTC(2011,4,9),0.6945]
];
```

from dbase SELECT I have:

```
$data_date = array();
$data_data = array();

foreach($STH as $row)
{

$date1 = $row['date'];
$date2 = explode("-", $date1);
$date3 = $date2[0].",".$date2[1].",".$date2[2];


$data_date[] = $date3;                      // date in scheme 2011,1,3
$data_data[] = $row['index_p_actual'];      // data like 0.7488
}
```

- info about date - $date_date[]
- info about corelated data - $data_data[]

I want to load data online, not via any external file like csv.

And my question is - how to join $data_date and $data_data into one data pocket to receive completly virtual list like

```
[Date.UTC(2011,1,3),0.7488],
[Date.UTC(2011,2,6),0.6983],
[Date.UTC(2011,3,8),0.6961],
[Date.UTC(2011,4,9),0.6945]
```

The suggestion from highcharts is to use:

```
series: [{
data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
}]
```

but I have $data & $date - how to join it? With php join I can use only one variable[] ...

Hmmm, or maybe another better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you well, I think you want to do this:

```
$data_date = array();
$data_data = array();

foreach($STH as $row)
{

$date1 = $row['date'];
$date2 = explode("-", $date1);
$date3 = $date2[0].",".$date2[1].",".$date2[2];


$data_date[] = $date3;                      // date in scheme 2011,1,3
$data_data[] = $row['index_p_actual'];      // data like 0.7488
$data_highcharts[] = [$date3,$row['index_p_actual']]

}
```

And then you send the `$data_highcharts[]` to your JavaScript which will have the format:

```
[[date1,data1],[date2,data2],...]
```

Comment: I understood your idea but we have there '[', 'Date', '.', 'UTC" ect. We can connect all this elements but, I think, it must be another way, simply one, typical for Highcharts system.

Comment: @Andrew I believe what I mentioned is simple because you just pass a variable to the JS that has all the points to plot.  But I hope somebody points out what you need :)

Comment: I try to load data via this way :)